# Creating a dynamic hyperlink that opens in a specific browser

Tags: javascript, html

< div class="last-call-number ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="lastCall.number.length != 10 && lastCall.number.length != 11">+12345678910

I want to modify this into a dynamic href link. I need to take the phone number which appears to be stored in the javascript as last-call-number and put it at the end of a url minus the +1 to look something like:

< a href="microsoft-edge:[http://myurl.com/2345678910">](http://myurl.com/2345678910%22%3E)

Comment: I should have stated this but I'm the end user of the website and just want to make a change for myself, I can only make changes to the html part of the site via inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

**If u have an input**

```
const anchor = document.getElementById("anchorID");
const input = document.getElementById("inputID");

input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    anchor.setAttribute('href', `microsoft-edge:http://myurl.com/+1${e.target.value}`);
});
```

**Else**

```
    const anchor = document.getElementById("anchorID");
    const span = document.getElementById("ID");
    
    anchor.setAttribute('href', `microsoft-edge:http://myurl.com/+1${span.innerHTML}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals like this:

```js
let last_call_number = '+12345678910'
// Splitting the string depends on the use case. You can also capture the last 10 digits of the number.
let number = last_call_number.split('+1')[1]

let url = `microsoft-edge:http://myurl.com/${number}`
console.log('URL:', url)
```